# MarkerSymbolizer of MultiLine not orientated in line direction (Mapnik, Mapbox)

Tags: mapbox, mapnik

*What I want:*

- drawing orientated arrows on one-directional streets

*What I tried so far:*

- **MarkerSymbolizer**: However, the arrows are all looking towards the "east" (right of the screen) instead of the direction of the MultiLineGeometry

*Code:*

```
<Rule>
  <LineSymbolizer />
  <MarkersSymbolizer marker-placement="line" file="arrow.png" width="1" />
</Rule>
```

**The data which is rendered here is a MultiLineString.**

*UPDATE:*

The only thing which I am missing right now in my solution posted below (using LinePatternSymbolizer) is that I cannot define spacing and max-error etc like [here](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/MarkersSymbolizer). Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I found the solution to my own question:*

Replace the MarkersSymbolizer with **LinePatternSymbolizer**, see below:

```
<Rule>
  <MaxScaleDenominator>250</MaxScaleDenominator>
  <LineSymbolizer stroke="#0000ff" stroke-width="84" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-opacity="0.5" smooth="1.0" />
  <LinePatternSymbolizer file="arrow.png" width="84" />
</Rule>
```

[see Documentation](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/LinePatternSymbolizer)

A workaround for the missing *spacing* attribute in LinePatternSymbolizer is so far to adjust the arrow.png image accordingly, e.g. more Spacing around the arrow in the image for a less frequent pattern.

[image]